# Numbers instead of letters with subfloat

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I have a document with a `figure` environment that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newbox\sf@box
\newenvironment{SubFloat}[2][]%
{\def\sf@one{#1}%
\def\sf@two{#2}%
\setbox\sf@box\hbox
\bgroup}%
{ \egroup
\ifx\@empty\sf@two\@empty\relax
\def\sf@two{\@empty}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\sf@one\@empty\relax
\subfloat[\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\else
\subfloat[\sf@one][\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{image1}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
\end{SubFloat}
\qquad
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{image2}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image2.jpg}
\end{SubFloat}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(compiled with `pdflatex`)

LaTeX puts letters below each image (`(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, etc..) and I want it to put numbers instead.

How could I do that?

Comment: Using `\renewcommand*\thesubfloatfigure{\themainfigure--\arabic{subfloatfigure}}` should do it. Adjust the `--` separator. While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: I'm sorry about the `MWE`, I know I should always include one with the question I just thought in this case it was a simple enough question not to need one (also I was lazy) Won't happen again. Quick follow-up question: where should I put the line you wrote? Above the figure? Will this also affect all the figures that come after that one? And, how should I adjust the `--`? Thank you very much!

Comment: Even if it is simple it is still better to compose one -- not everyone is familiar every aspect of LaTeX, so that would help others.  Plus with all software (well and hardware as well), unless it can be tested it you have to assume it does _not_ work.  As far as your question, if you want it to effect the entire document, put it in your preamble. If you want the effect localized, put it in a group, after `\begin{figure}` should work, but I can't test it without a MWE, so you'll have to do that...

Comment: You're right, I've added the `MWE` now. I still don't quite get how should I adjust the `--`. What do I do with those dashes? Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For redefine the label for the `subfig` package use:

```
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
```

To keep the effect localized, use this within the `figure` environment as I have done below. As you can see in the subsequent use the labels are restored to using the default of `(a)` format:

[image]

If you want this to effect your entire document simply add the `\renewcommand` to the preamble.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% <----- remove "demo" option for real use
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}% For image capture

\makeatletter
\newbox\sf@box
\newenvironment{SubFloat}[2][]%
{\def\sf@one{#1}%
\def\sf@two{#2}%
\setbox\sf@box\hbox
\bgroup}%
{ \egroup
\ifx\@empty\sf@two\@empty\relax
\def\sf@two{\@empty}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\sf@one\@empty\relax
\subfloat[\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\else
\subfloat[\sf@one][\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\textcolor{red}{With} \verb|\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}| within the \verb|figure|:

\centering
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{image1}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
\end{SubFloat}
\qquad
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{image2}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image2.jpg}
\end{SubFloat}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\textcolor{red}{Without} \verb|\renewcommand*\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}|

\centering
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{image1}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image1.jpg}
\end{SubFloat}
\qquad
\begin{SubFloat}
{\label{image2}}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image2.jpg}
\end{SubFloat}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! I've found it also works without the `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` line, could this be right? Regards.

Comment: The `demo` option was used as I did not have your figures. One of the other packages is including `graphicx` so that is why you don't need that line.  If you are curious, you can add `\listfiles` _before_ `begin{document}` and in the log file you will see the version of the packages that are being included.

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\arabic{subfigure}}
```

in your preamble, then the subfigures will be numbered as (1), (2) and so on. However a `\ref{label1}` would print

> 11

which is obviously wrong. So you have also to add something like

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure--}
\makeatother
```

so that `\ref{label1}` will print

> 1--1

(change the separator as you wish).

---

Your definition of the `SubFloat` environment can be improved in a couple of ways.

1. Standard LaTeX

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newsavebox{\sf@box}
   \newenvironment{SubFloat}[2][]
     {\def\sf@one{#1}\def\sf@two{#2}%
      \begin{lrbox}{\sf@box}}%
     {\end{lrbox}%
      \ifx\@empty\sf@one
        \subfloat[\sf@two]{\box\sf@box}%
      \else
        \subfloat[\sf@one][\sf@two]{\usebox\sf@box}%
      \fi}
   \makeatother
   ```

   (Your test for emptiness add redundant tokens.)
2. With `xparse`

   ```
   \usepackage{xparse}
   \makeatletter
   \newsavebox\sf@box
   \NewDocumentEnvironment{SubFloat}{ o m }
    {\begin{lrbox}{\sf@box}}
    {\end{lrbox}%
     \IfNoValueTF{#1}
      {\subfloat[#2]{\usebox{\sf@box}}}
      {\subfloat[#1][#2]{\usebox{\sf@box}}}%
    }
   \makeatother
   ```

   As you see you don't need any low level test: the package can distinguish by itself if the optional argument is not present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @egreg but I'll admit that your definitions of the `subfloat` environment went way over my head since I didn't define it in my document, I'm just using a template I downloaded. I'm sure others (with a deeper LaTeX coding understanding) will find it very useful though. Cheers.

Comment: @Gabriel That's the problem in copying templates from "untrusted" sources. That definition is rather poor LaTeX programming.

Comment: Really?? That's odd, it comes from a pretty well known PhD template (in spanish) called Texis (http://gaia.fdi.ucm.es/research/texis) In any case it has worked rather well for me so far, so I'm very grateful to the authors for developing and making it available on line. Since I know pretty much nothing about LaTeX coding, I'll have to take your word on the poor coding. Regards and thanks again!